How do I get the vscoq client and the vscoq lsp to work with Neovim?
I am trying to use the Neovim client vscoq.nvim which uses the vscoq lsp.
I have currently installed the vscoq lsp globally and am using it with VSCode, but I'd like to use it with Neovim. I use Lazy and nvim-lspconfig with mason and have my lspconfig.lua set up in the following way:
return {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    "tomtomjhj/vscoq.nvim",
    event = { "BufReadPre", "BufNewFile" },
    dependencies = {
        "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp",
        { "antosha417/nvim-lsp-file-operations", config = true },
    },
    config = function()
        -- import lspconfig plugin
        local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")
        local util = require("lspconfig/util")
        -- import cmp-nvim-lsp plugin
        local cmp_nvim_lsp = require("cmp_nvim_lsp")
        local keymap = vim.keymap -- for conciseness
        local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
        local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
            opts.buffer = bufnr
            -- set keybinds
            opts.desc = "Show LSP references"
            keymap.set("n", "gR", "<cmd>Telescope lsp_references<CR>", opts) -- show definition, references
            -- more keybinds ...
        end
        -- used to enable autocompletion (assign to every lsp server config)
        local capabilities = cmp_nvim_lsp.default_capabilities()
        -- configure python server
        lspconfig["pyright"].setup({
            capabilities = capabilities,
            on_attach = on_attach,
        })
        -- configure vscoq server
        require("vscoq").setup({
            vscoq = {
                proof = {
                    -- In manual mode, don't move the cursor when stepping forward/backward a command
                    cursor = { sticky = true },
                },
            },
            lsp = {
                capabilities = capabilities,
                filetypes = { "coq" },
                on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
                    -- your mappings, etc

                    -- In manual mode, use ctrl-alt-{j,k,l} to step.
                    vim.keymap.set({ "n", "i" }, "<C-M-j>", "<Cmd>VsCoq stepForward<CR>", { buffer = bufnr })
                    vim.keymap.set({ "n", "i" }, "<C-M-k>", "<Cmd>VsCoq stepBackward<CR>", { buffer = bufnr })
                    vim.keymap.set({ "n", "i" }, "<C-M-l>", "<Cmd>VsCoq interpretToPoint<CR>", { buffer = bufnr })
                end,
                autostart = true, -- use this if you want to manually `:LspStart vscoqtop`.
            },
        })
    end,
}


When I use this configuration, I cannot see any language servers in the Configured servers list: not even those working earlier (python, go, etc.)
I am still getting familiar with customizing my nvim config and would love it if someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.
